# Custom Property, interact with parent class on `set`

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, properties, scope

I am trying to build a custom property.

When I set the property, I want to interact with an object in the parent. For the life of me I cant seem to figure it out. I keep on getting the same errors.

*"Cannot refer to an instance or member of a class from within a shared method or member without an explicit instance initialized"*

```
Public Class myItem

    Property heading1 As c_heading1

    Private Class c_heading1

        Private newTextValue As String
        Public Property text() As String
            Get
                Return newTextValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                newTextValue = value
                _set_heading_1_text(value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Private newColorValue As System.Drawing.Color
        Public Property color() As System.Drawing.Color
            Get
                Return newColorValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As System.Drawing.Color)
                newColorValue = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
    Shared Sub _set_heading_1_text(t As String)
        h1.Text = t '///I get the error here, and the same error when I try to access h1 from within the "text" property setter.
    End Sub

End Class
```

***EXTRA INFO***

Irrespective of my efforts here (which may be the totally wrong way to do it, here is what I am essentially trying to do.)

I have a usercontrol (uc). On my usercontrol, I have a label (l).

I can normally call uc.l , from my form using the control. This way I can interact with the label directly, from my form code that uses the usercontrol.

What I am trying to do now, is to essentially "hide" l, (I dont want the calling form to be able to interact with the label directly).

I want to create an accessible custom object in the uc, exposing only 2 properties.

When these properties are set from the form calling the usercontrol, I want to set the original label's properties, from the new property setters I created for my custom object.

I can easily just create two properties in the UC itself, one for (l)text, and one for (l)color.

But I have multiple labels on the uc, and I would like to reference a custom object for each, exposing specific custom properties.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If I remove shared from the sub, I get "Reference to non shared member requires an instance" from the setter code calling the sub. I also cant call h1 from the setter code directly, as it give me the same error. h1 is a label, it wont call the custom text property. I am building a user control and essentially want to "hide" the label and all its properties from the code using the user control, hence my custom properties.

Comment: sorry, I misread that _set_heading was outside the private class.  what is H1 and where did it come from?  `heading1.Text = t` should work (without Shared) once you create an instance of it.

Comment: h1 is a label on the user control.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I am trying to do. I can call the property just fine, what I cant do, is interact with the h1 label, from the setter.

Comment: are you trying to have a property change to `heading1` trickle to another control/object?  INotifyPropertyChanged might work better for that. That code is illegal in other ways: you cant have a Public Property exposing a Private type.  `Shared` on that sub lets you call it from the private class, but as a Shared method it cant reference other instance members (like H1)

Comment: Ok, I updated my question for a bit more clarity on what I am attempting. Thanks.

Comment: If you dont want the form tinkering with the label, set the Modifier property to Private.  Then you can create methods on the UserControl to do whatever via code

Comment: I was looking at using methods, but then my assignments would look like `uc.heading1.whatever("")`.  I would like it to be `uc.heading1.whatever = ""` .

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, I really appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `c_heading1` is meant to mirror or control the label to some extent.  For that just use the actual label as the backing field for some new properties:

**Plus new info:** *I have 3 labels... and I don;t want to create 6 properties*

```
Public Class UC

    Public Property HeadingA As HeaderLabel
    Public Property HeadingB As HeaderLabel
    Public Property HeadingC As HeaderLabel

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        ' important
        HeadingA = New HeaderLabel(Label1)
        HeadingB = New HeaderLabel(Label2)
        HeadingC = New HeaderLabel(Label3)

    End Sub

    Public Class HeaderLabel
        Public Property Text As String
            Get
                Return myLabel.Text
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                ' do something fabulous
                myLabel.Text = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Color As Color
            Get
                Return myLabel.BackColor
            End Get
            Set(value As Color)
                ' do soemthing else fabulous
                myLabel.BackColor = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private myLabel As Label
        Public Sub New(lbl As Label)
            myLabel = lbl
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

`I dont want the calling form to be able to interact with the label directly`

If you set the `Modifiers` property to `Private` on the UserControl, the form will no longer be able to reference it.

Usage:

```
    Uc1.HeadingA.Text = "Something Fabulous"
    Uc1.HeadingA.Color = Color.AliceBlue
```

Comment: Thanks, I still think we are not on the same page :-). I have 3 labels... and I don;t want to create 6 properties like this: 
`l1_text, l1_color, l2_text, l2_color, l3_text, l3_color`

I want to call 3 main properties (l1,l2,l3), and set two fields on each property:  (l1.text, l1.color) (l2.text, l2.color) (l3.text, l3.color.)

Comment: I think I have figured out what I am doing wrong (in how I am trying to use it), will report back shortly.

Comment: `I have 3 labels... and I don;t want to create 6 properties` we can only go by whatever info you provide.  Update is similar to what you have but isnt glued to specific controls

Comment: That is exactly it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this. I would have liked to call .text and .color directly from _load here in this example, but with help from @Plutonix , I don't think that is possible?

```
Public Class awsumlistItem

    Private new_heading1 As LabelProperties
    Public Property heading1 As LabelProperties
        Get
            Return new_heading1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As LabelProperties)
            new_heading1 = value
            h1.Text = new_heading1.text
            h1.color = new_heading1.color
        End Set
    End Property

    Private new_heading2 As LabelProperties
    Public Property heading2 As LabelProperties
        Get
            Return new_heading2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As LabelProperties)
            new_heading2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private new_heading3 As LabelProperties
    Public Property heading3 As LabelProperties
        Get
            Return new_heading3
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As LabelProperties)
            new_heading3 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class LabelProperties

        Public Property text() As String
        Public Property color() As System.Drawing.Color

    End Class


    Private Sub awsumlistItem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        '  Me.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        Dim myHeading1 As New LabelProperties

        With myHeading1
            .text = "blah blah"
            .color = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua
        End With

        heading1 = myHeading1


    End Sub



End Class
```